# Trying to get property 'photos' of non-object Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I try to show image from product_galleries table with related to products table but I got this error. In my products table have 'id' field and in products galleries have 'products_id' field. I already try to google it but still don't get the answer to solve my problem

Thank you

Here is my home.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
                    @php $incrementProduct = 0 @endphp
                    @forelse ($products as $product)
                        <div
                            class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"
                            data-aos="fade-up"
                            data-aos-delay="{{ $incrementProduct+=100 }}" >
                            <a href="{{ route('detail', $product->slug) }}" class="component-products d-block">
                                <div class="products-thumbnail">
                                    <div
                                        class="products-image"
                                        style="
                                            @if($product->galleries)
                                                background-image: url('{{ Storage::url($product->galleries->first()->photos) }}')

                                            @else
                                                background-color: #eee"
                                            @endif 
                                    >
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="products-text">{{ $product->name }}</div>
                                <div class="products-price">{{ $product->price }}</div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    @empty
                        <div class="col-12 text-center py-5" data-aos="fade-up"
                            data-aos-delay="100">
                            No Product Found
                        </div>
                    @endforelse
                    
                </div>
```

My HomeController.php

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::take(6)->get();
        $products = Product::with(['galleries'])->take(8)->get();

        return view('pages.home', [
            'categories' => $categories,
            'products' => $products
        ]);
    }
}
```

My Product.php Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'users_id', 'categories_id', 'price', 'description', 'slug'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [

    ];


    public function galleries() {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductGallery::class, 'products_id', 'id');
    }


    public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'users_id');
    }

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'categories_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

My ProductGallery.php Model

```
class ProductGallery extends Model
{


    protected $fillable = [
        'photos', 'products_id'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [

    ];

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'products_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: `$product->galleries->first()->photos` - This line is unsafe. If any instance of `$prduct->galleries->first()` is `null`, then you're trying to do `null->photos`, which is not going to work. You're checking `@if($product->galleries)`, but `$product->galleries` will be a `Collection`, which is always `true` inside an `if` statement. `@if($product->galleries->first())`, or `@unless($product->galleries->isEmpty())`, then the rest of your code should work.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you for the comment, I already tried with @unless($product->galleries->isEmpty()) ...... Storage::url($product->galleries->first()->photos) and the result is no image display.

Comment: Then you need to debug what `Storage::url($product->galleries->first()->photos)`; if that is a valid URL, then check your CSS. If it's `null` (or something else), then it won't display. You're not getting an error anymore, so now it's up to you to debug further; I can't help as I have no idea what `->photos` returns, or if it works with `Storage::url()`.